# Best way to re/use redis connections for prometheus django exporter

Tags: python, django, redis, celery, prometheus

I am getting an error

```
redis.exceptions.ConnectionError: Error 24 connecting to redis-service:6379. Too many open files.
...
OSError: [Errno 24] Too many open files
```

I know this can be fixed by increasing the `ulimit` but I don't think that's the issue here and also this is a service running on a container.
The application starts up correctly works for 48 hours correctly and then I get the above error.
Which implies that the connections are growing over time exponentially.

What my application is basically doing

> - background_task (ran using celery) -> collects data from postgres and sets it on redis
> - prometheus reaches the app at '/metrics' which is a django view -> collects data from redis and serves the data using django prometheus exporter

The code looks something like this

`views.py`

```py
from prometheus_client.core import GaugeMetricFamily, REGISTRY
from my_awesome_app.taskbroker.celery import app


class SomeMetricCollector:

    def get_sample_metrics(self):
        with app.connection_or_acquire() as conn:
            client = conn.channel().client
            result = client.get('some_metric_key')
            return {'some_metric_key': result}

    def collect(self):
        sample_metrics = self.get_sample_metrics()
        for key, value in sample_metrics.items():
            yield GaugeMetricFamily(key, 'This is a custom metric', value=value)


REGISTRY.register(SomeMetricCollector())
```

`tasks.py`

```
# This is my boilerplate taskbroker app
from my_awesome_app.taskbroker.celery import app
# How it's collecting data from postgres is trivial to this issue.
from my_awesome_app.utility_app.utility import some_value_calculated_from_query


@app.task()
def app_metrics_sync_periodic():
    with app.connection_or_acquire() as conn:
        client = conn.channel().client
        client.set('some_metric_key', some_value_calculated_from_query(), ex=21600)
        return True
```

I don't think the background data collection in `tasks.py` is causing the Redis connections to grow exponentially but it's the Django view `'/metrics'` in `views.py` which is causing.

Can you please tell me what I am doing wrong here?
If there is a better way to read from Redis from a Django view. The Prometheus instance scrapes the Django application every `5s`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answer is according to my use case and research.

The issue here, according to me, is the fact that each request to `/metrics` initiates a new thread where the `views.py` creates new connections in the `Celery` broker's connection pool.

This can be easily handled by letting `Django` manage its own `Redis` connection pool through [cache backend](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/cache/) and `Celery` manage its own `Redis` connection pool and not use each other's connection pools from their respective threads.

### Django Side

`config.py`

```py
# CACHES
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# For more details on options for your cache backend please refer
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/settings/#backend
CACHES = {
    "default": {
        "BACKEND": "django_redis.cache.RedisCache",
        "LOCATION": "redis://localhost:6379/0",
        "OPTIONS": {
            "CLIENT_CLASS": "django_redis.client.DefaultClient",
        },
    }
}
```

`views.py`

```py
from prometheus_client.core import GaugeMetricFamily, REGISTRY
# *: Replacing celery app with Django cache backend
from django.core.cache import cache


class SomeMetricCollector:

    def get_sample_metrics(self):
        # *: This is how you will get the new client, which is still context managed.
        with cache.client.get_client() as client:
            result = client.get('some_metric_key')
            return {'some_metric_key': result}

    def collect(self):
        sample_metrics = self.get_sample_metrics()
        for key, value in sample_metrics.items():
            yield GaugeMetricFamily(key, 'This is a custom metric', value=value)


REGISTRY.register(SomeMetricCollector())
```

> This will ensure that `Django` will maintain it's `Redis` connection pool and not cause new connections to be spun up unnecessarily.

### Celery Side

`tasks.py`

```py
# This is my boilerplate taskbroker app
from my_awesome_app.taskbroker.celery import app
# How it's collecting data from postgres is trivial to this issue.
from my_awesome_app.utility_app.utility import some_value_calculated_from_query


@app.task()
def app_metrics_sync_periodic():
    with app.connection_or_acquire() as conn:
        # *: This will force celery to always look into the existing connection pool for connection.
        client = conn.default_channel.client
        client.set('some_metric_key', some_value_calculated_from_query(), ex=21600)
        return True
```

### How do I monitor connections?

- There is a nice [prometheus celery exporter](https://github.com/OvalMoney/celery-exporter) which will help you monitor your celery task activity not sure how you can add connection pool and connection monitoring to it.
- The easiest way to manually verify if the connections are growing every time `/metrics` is hit on the web app, is by:

  ```sh
  $ redis-cli
  127.0.0.1:6379> CLIENT LIST
  ...
  ```
- The [client list](https://redis.io/commands/client-list) command will help you see if the number of connections are growing or not.
- I don't use queues sadly but I would recommend using queues. This is how my worker runs:

  ```sh
  $ celery -A  my_awesome_app.taskbroker worker --concurrency=20 -l ERROR -E
  ```